# Trying to upload new apk to Google Play

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, sha1

I uploaded my first application to Google Play and that app has a Google map. Unfortunatelly I published the app with debug key, so people cannot see the map. Now I realized and want to upload a new version with release key but it shows me a message saying that my SHA1 is different from the apk already published and the operation is not possible.
I have tried to unpublish current apk and upload the new one but it seems not possible...It seems not possible to delete older apks neither... Is there some solution to my problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you will have to upload it as a different APK, there's no updating an app with different digital signature

Answer (score 0):

No need to delete the app or un-publish it. Just upload another APK with following instructions. 
You are getting error of SHA1 because you are signing APK with different keys. You have to use the same key with which you signed last APK.
In addition you will have to change the android version and android code name in android manifest file.

Comment: But my SHA1 changed the moment I did a release key, that it is what I need in order to people being albe to see the map in my app... Cannot go back and use a debug key in order to have the same SHA1 right?